# vb.net query to display specific rows of table

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, t-sql

How do I display the specific rows returned by the query in a table?

Query code is

```
SELECT name, STD, Fees, paid
FROM  register
WHERE (paid - Fees < 0)
```

I get error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

But when I return all rows it works fine.

How do I display only specific rows?

I used

```
Dim test As DataTable
test = Me.RegisterTableAdapter.GetDataBy ' GetDataBy is Query    
DataGridView1.DataSource = test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and create a stored procedure and call it from .net to populate your datatable/Datagridview. (put your select statement into a stored proc from whatever SQL you are using)

Examples on how to do this below. 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-Fill-Populate-DataTable-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?462392-RESOLVED-Using-stored-procedure-to-populate-a-VB-Datatable